# Uncaught TypeError: this.saveValue is not a function

Tags: javascript

I have a script like this

```
var EditorView = elementor.modules.controls.BaseData.extend({
        onReady() {
            this.control_select = this.$el.find('.js-example-basic-multiple');
            this.control_select.select2({});
            this.control_select.on('change', function (e) {
                this.saveValue();
            });
        },
        saveValue() {
            this.setValue(this.control_select.val());
        },
        onBeforeDestroy() {
            this.saveValue();
            this.ui.textarea[0].emojioneArea.off();
        }
    });
```

why can't I access the saveValue function?

Comment: are you getting the error inside the change callback ? if then that is because the context is lost. Try using ```()=>``` function

Comment: @gvmani yes problem is there, so change do I have to change that function?

Comment: @gvmani thanks error is gone

Answer (score 0):

The value of `this` in a new JavaScript function refers to the global value. In your case it will be `window` as you appear to be running this on the browser.

You can learn more about `this` behaviour on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

To solve your problem you can use an arrow function, in which behavior of `this` is [different](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#arrow_functions_used_as_methods).

```
this.control_select.on('change', (e) => {
   this.saveValue();
});
```